# Moving animation in 2d game

Tags: java, 2d

I'm making a simple 2d shooter like space invaders, and I want to move my "enemy" only horizontally, from one side to another with the same speed.
How can I do that?

I have already did it for my "hero" with a `KeyListener` but I don't know how to do it automatically.

Here there's some code that might help.

```
public SimpleEnemy(String linkimg, int x, int y, int life) {
    super(linkimg, x, y);
    this.life=life;
    this.isMoving=false;
}

public void move() {
    x += dx;
    y += dy;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a game loop. For example a while-loop that never ends (endless-loop) and which updates your hero position if needed.

```
while (true) {
    // insert statement if move is needed here
    move();
}
```

That's a pretty basic example but it should make things clear.

Since I assume that you are using java, you can take a look at some game frameworks like [jgame](http://www.13thmonkey.org/~boris/jgame/). These frameworks take a similar approach and make it more comfortable to work with.

Edit:

Note that processors are running extremely fast these days and this endless-loop will be run very very often in a small amount of time (like 1000+ times per second). So you might have to limit the execution time of this loop, or your hero will be outside the screen faster you can look.

You can achive this with a sleep or something similar. Also these frameworks I mentioned will have this limitation on board.

Comment: if i have pretty understand, i have added something that may help, a timer in the board, 
    like timer = new Timer(5, this);    
    timer.start();
am i right?

Comment: a timer also would do the job in this little game. Take care that you create only one timer and update all your game objects in this one timer.

Comment: ok i'll use the endless loop. But where i have to put it? Into my paint method?

Comment: Not into your paint method. I seems you have a class named SimpleEnemy. Then you should also have got a main class. put it into your main method. e.g.
`public static void main(string[] args) { SimpleEnemy enemy = new SimpleEnemy("image",0,0,100); while(true) { enemy.move() } }`

Comment: you could edit your question and add some more code to make it easier to point you into the right direction.